# x+y-z between -1 and 1

Tags: algorithm, list, language-agnostic, integer

Let `[a_1 a_2 ... a_n]` be a list of **distinct** integers in the range `[1,10n]`. Give an algorithm that returns `true` if there are three distinct elements `x,y,z` such that `-1 <= x+y-z <= 1`, and `false` otherwise.

A brute force algorithm (checking all possible combinations of `x+y-z`, runs in time `O(n^3)`. Are there more efficient algorithms?

Comment: Are you having a specific problem while trying to implement this, or are you just posting your homework problem verbatim?

Comment: Nope, I don't have a problem with implementing the brute force algo. I was wondering whether there are more efficient algorithms.

Comment: Why the down & close votes? :\

Comment: @amit: It is an algorithm problem phrased as a general programming question, so it is hard to see what the user is looking for. Additionally people tend to close questions that they think can't be answered. Too localized is the primary reason right now, I disagree but can see where they are coming from.

Comment: @Guvante There are many problems such as this in SO. The OP asked a specific question, and showed his effort (brute force solution). It is OK to ask for a better approach, or "how can it be done?" after showing some effort. In addition - if something "cannot be answered" (in this case, if there is no better solution) - a good answer will be to explain why (Many times it is the cases when people are asking about NP-Hard problems, for example)

Comment: @amit: I agree, and gave an upvote. I guess thinking more a minimal amount of algo work in your past would point to "too localised" but in general it is a good question.

Comment: @amit Looking at the edit history, there was no question when originally posted. It was added after downvotes and close votes were incurred. (That's when I changed my downvote to an upvote, but I'm sure many people will never come back and see that it was improved.)

Comment: @Wiseguy: Nevertheless - at least one voter (@S.L.Barth) voted AFTER the edit - I believe there were more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Here is an `O(n^2)` worst case algorithm that uses `O(n)` additional space.

The idea is to check for all possible pairs (instead of triples), and iteratively marks which elements you have already seen, and compare against them the sum of each pair.

For each pair, check its sum has matching element which is exactly the sum (`x+y-z == 0`) or an element you can get to if you add 1 (`x+y+1-z == 0 -> x+y-z = -1`) or you can get to if you reduce 1 (`x+y-1-z == 0 -> x + y - z == 1`)

Pseudo code:

```
mark = new boolean[10n]; //all initialized to false
sort arr //O(nlogn)
for each i in n,1: (reverse order)
   for each j in 1,i-1:
      //neglected range check, make sure it is done
      if (mark[arr[i]+arr[j]] || mark[arr[i]+arr[j]+1] || mark[arr[i]+arr[j]-1]):
          return true
      mark[arr[i]] = true
return false
```

Note that we iterate `i` from `n` to 1, because `z > x` and `z > y` - and we want to make sure we are checking all pairs with element that is already in the list if it is there

**Correctness Proof:**

If there is a solution `x+y-z = 0` - then `z > x` and `z > y` (all elements are positive distinct integers). 

Without loss of generality, let's assume `x > y`. So, when iterating `arr[i]=x` in outer loop, there is some `j<i` such that `arr[j]=y`. Also, since `z>x` - `mark[z] == true` - since we marked it when we previously iterated it.

Thus: The algorithm will find `mark[arr[x] + arr[y]] == true`, and yield `true`.

similar proof for the `+-1` cases.

If the algorithm yielded true, then it found one of the conditions true. Let's assume it is `mark[arr[i] + arr[j]]` (The proof for the other cases will be similar).

So, we found out `mark[arr[i] + arr[j]] == true` - so we inserted it since there is some element `z` such that `z = arr[i] + arr[j]`, and the algorithm is correct for this case.

Comment: Nice algorithm! It's interesting whether there exists an `O(n log n)` algorithm.